# How can I convert this OpenCV Smart Light Random Memory Sprays Retinex C++ code to OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, opencv

I have been trying to convert the **Smart Light Random Memory Sprays Retinex** project from [Image Processing Group - Color constancy](https://ipg.fer.hr/ipg/resources/color_constancy) into C# code with the OpenCVSharp library.

This is the function I'm stuck on.

```
void RandomMemorySpraysRetinexPerformWhiteBalance(Mat source, Mat &destination, int N, int n, double upperBound, int rowsStep, int colsStep, double rFactor){
    
    int rows=source.rows;
    int cols=source.cols;

    int R=rFactor*sqrt((double)(rows*rows+cols*cols))+0.5;

    Mat normalized;
    source.convertTo(normalized, CV_64FC3);

    int outputRows=rows/rowsStep;
    int outputCols=cols/colsStep;
    destination=Mat(outputRows, outputCols, CV_64FC3);

    Vec3d *input=(Vec3d *)normalized.data;
    Vec3d *inputPoint=input;
    Vec3d *output=(Vec3d *)destination.data;
    Vec3d *outputPoint=output;

    RNG random;

    CartesianTree<double> **qhs;

    qhs=new CartesianTree<double>*[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;++i){
        qhs[i]=new CartesianTree<double>[3];
    }

    for (int outputRow=0;outputRow<outputRows;++outputRow){
        for (int outputCol=0;outputCol<outputCols;++outputCol){
            
            int row=outputRow*rowsStep;
            int col=outputCol*colsStep;

            inputPoint=input+row*cols+col;
            outputPoint=output+outputRow*outputCols+outputCol;
            
            Vec3d &currentPoint=*inputPoint;
            Vec3d &finalPoint=*outputPoint;
            finalPoint=Vec3d(0, 0, 0);

            for (int i=0;i<N;++i){
                
                Vec3d max=Vec3d(0, 0, 0);

                while(qhs[i][0].Size()<n){
                    double angle=2*CV_PI*random.uniform(0.0, 1.0);
                    double r=R*random.uniform(0.0, 1.0);

                    int newRow=row+r*sin(angle);
                    int newCol=col+r*cos(angle);

                    if (newRow>=0 && newRow<rows && newCol>=0 && newCol<cols){
                        Vec3d &newPoint=input[newRow*cols+newCol];
                        for (int k=0;k<3;++k){
                            qhs[i][k].Push(newPoint[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int k=0;k<3;++k){
                    if (max[k]<qhs[i][k].Max()){
                        max[k]=qhs[i][k].Max();
                    }
                    
                    qhs[i][k].Pop();

                }

                for (int k=0;k<3;++k){
                    if (max[k]==0){
                        max[k]=1;
                    }
                    finalPoint[k]+=currentPoint[k]/max[k];
                }

            }
            
            finalPoint/=N;

            for (int i=0;i<3;++i){
                if (finalPoint[i]>1){
                    finalPoint[i]=1;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<N;++i){
        delete[] qhs[i];
    }
    delete[] qhs;

    double scaleFactor=upperBound;
    
    if (rowsStep>1 || colsStep>1){
        resize(destination, destination, source.size());
    }

    destination=destination*scaleFactor-1;

    destination.convertTo(destination, source.type());

}
```

I'm having trouble converting these two sections to equivalent OpenCVSharp code.

```
Vec3d *input=(Vec3d *)normalized.data;
Vec3d *inputPoint=input;
Vec3d *output=(Vec3d *)destination.data;
Vec3d *outputPoint=output;
```

```
inputPoint=input+row*cols+col;
outputPoint=output+outputRow*outputCols+outputCol;
```

I originally tried converting what I could to OpenCVSharp and then making the function unsafe and leaving the rest of the function alone, but this resulted in a black image for the result.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).